# ExecJS::RuntimeError in Aaa_core#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails application was working fine until I typed the following command line into the Windows cmd prompt: "bundle exec rake assets:clean". After I did this and went into rails server again, the following error popped up on the homepage.

How do I get rid of the below-mentioned error OR how do I reverse whatever "bundle exec rake assets:clean" did to cause this error?

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Aaa_core#index
Showing C:/Sites/AAA_Website_new/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised: 
  (in C:/Sites/AAA_Website_new/app/assets/javascripts/aaa_core.js.coffee)

Extracted source (around line #7): 
4:   <meta charset="utf-8">
5:   <title><%=title%></title>
6:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
7:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
8:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
9: </head>
10: <body>
```

Here is the application trace:
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__51027894_38988708'

I already tried "bundle install", and here is my list of gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
actionmailer (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
actionpack (4.0.0, 4.0.0.rc2, 3.2.14)
activemodel (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
activerecord (4.0.0, 3.2.14)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.12)
activeresource (3.2.14)
activesupport (4.0.0, 4.0.0.rc2, 3.2.14)
ansi (1.4.3)
arel (4.0.0, 3.0.2)
atomic (1.1.10)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2 x86-mingw32, 3.1.1 x86-mingw32)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.1.4, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
coffee-rails (4.0.0, 3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
cucumber (1.3.6)
devise (3.0.3)
diff-lcs (1.2.4, 1.1.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.4.0)
factory_girl (1.3.3)
factory_girl_rails (1.0)
faker (0.3.1)
gherkin (2.12.1 x86-mingw32)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.5, 0.6.4)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.0.4)
json (1.8.0, 1.5.5)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.24, 1.23)
mini_portile (0.5.1)
minitest (4.7.5, 2.5.1)
multi_json (1.7.9, 1.7.7)
multi_test (0.0.2)
nokogiri (1.6.0 x86-mingw32)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
pg (0.16.0 x86-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.14)
railties (3.2.14)
rake (10.1.0, 0.9.2.2)
rb-readline (0.5.0)
rdoc (3.12.2, 3.9.5)
ref (1.0.5)
rspec (2.14.1, 2.6.0)
rspec-core (2.14.5, 2.6.4)
rspec-expectations (2.14.2, 2.6.0)
rspec-mocks (2.14.3, 2.6.0)
rspec-rails (2.6.1)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
sass (3.2.10)
sass-rails (4.0.0, 3.2.6)
sprockets (2.10.0, 2.2.2)
sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.8 x86-mingw32, 1.3.7 x86-mingw32)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.2)
tilt (1.4.1)
tiny_tds (0.6.1 x86-mingw32)
treetop (1.4.15, 1.4.14)
turn (0.9.6)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uglifier (2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.1.2)
warden (1.2.3)
webrat (0.7.1)
```

Comment: Great details provided, but what's the question?

Comment: How do I get rid of the above-mentioned error OR how do I reverse whatever "bundle exec rake assets:clean" did to cause this error?

Comment: Put that into the question

Comment: Can anyone help please? I know one solution is removing the "//= require_tree ." line from application.js file, but that is not a permanent solution.